# Unable to copy file in Array : Shell Script

Tags: arrays, shell

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0


while read line
do 

    for WORD in $line
    do
        #copy to array
    array[$i]=$WORD
    i=$((i+1))
    done

done < ACTION_TAG.txt
```

File is saved with name .sh

I am trying to copy a file in array. it throws below error.

```
read.sh: 44: array[0]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[1]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[2]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[3]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[4]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[5]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[6]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[7]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[8]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[9]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[10]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[11]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[12]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[13]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[14]=sg: not found
read.sh: 44: array[15]=sg: not found
```

I went through the same queries posted on stackoverflow but was unable to solve problem. can some one help.

Comment: I have just tested this code with some sample text and it worked as expected, could you provide some sample text from the file that causes the error?

Comment: what do you mean by sample text

Comment: HI, Can you please let me know if u modified anything

Comment: my code was exactly the same as yours, the only things I can think that might be different is your input file or that I use BASH as my shell(most people prefer zsh or ksh because they're faster).

Comment: there is some problem.. i am not able to deal with arrays @ all. Event the example program  are not running from websites

Comment: hi !! i tested the same code on ...other desktop with linux..it works fine..what could be the issue

Comment: Are you using bash? Try changing the `sh` in the shebang with `bash`, or running your test script with `bash read.sh`

Comment: yeah... same results.. doesnt work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52094/discussion-between-scragar-and-user2598064)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong shebang here `#!/bin/sh` If you want to use BASH array then use:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Also to store various words in array you can use this much simplified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=()
while read line
do 
    array+=( $line )
done < ACTION_TAG.txt
```

Comment: YOUR CODE GIVES ERROR read.sh: 28: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: You need to make sure to run this script as `bash ./script.sh`